# Flutter application on Android `private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path`

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

I was facing some issue, with my flutter app. And after upgrading the `Gradle` version I started facing this issue. And i couldn't find anything close to this, after googling. But later I solved it from a different issue. SO I decided to create a issue for someone who's looking up this same issue.

Bcz I had no idea what to try. I was almost lost.

```
Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @36297cd9
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To solve the issue, you have to add this line to your `gradle.properties` file.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
```

And your `grade.properties` file should look something like this ->
[image]

For me, it solved the issue. And then I had a different issue. But for that I just updated my `kotlin` version inside `android/build.gradle` file. And then, finally my project ran.

> If anyone knows this issue in depth, and wants to explain the situation a bit more, I would really appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: I am using code from GitHub and this solution solved my problem. Thank you very much

Comment: I've been wasting my two days in search of a solution. I'm glad to see this one and it worked perfectly. THANK YOU!